# Install xubuntu-desktop on Debian OS

Tags: linux, debian, desktop-environment, xubuntu

I have installed this Debian distro:

```
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:    7.8
Codename:   wheezy
```

I want to install `xubuntu-desktop` which is available on Ubuntu repo.
Any help?

Comment: Just install [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) instead... (Debian 7 is old, you should at least start with Debian 8 if you want to use Debian.)

Comment: Hmm. That would be better. But I want learn how to do it properly on Debian wheezy. Testing it on VirtualBox with an old ISO I had. Let's see.

Comment: There's no "proper way" to do it on Debian Wheezy. `xubuntu-desktop` is a package designed for Xubuntu, the proper way is to use it there — you shouldn't arbitrarily mix and match packages from different distributions (unless the packages are designed for use on multiple distributions).

Comment: I've been using `xubuntu-desktop` on Ubuntu. So I thought it would be okay on Debian too as Ubuntu is based on Debian.

Comment: Xubuntu is [an official flavour of Ubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/about/), and all the Xubuntu-specific packages are actually hosted in the Ubuntu repositories (*e.g.* [`xubuntu-meta`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-meta) provides `xubuntu-desktop`). So it's easy to install Xubuntu in Ubuntu. None of the Xubuntu-specific packages are available in Debian. You can install Xfce in Debian (including Wheezy), which will get you close, but if you want Xubuntu you should just run Xubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Xubuntu is Ubuntu for Xfce as desktop manager.

xubuntu-desktop is a virtual package that installs Xfce and some useful desktop utilities on Ubuntu. Trying to install on Debian is asking for a world of pain.

You can of course install Xfce on Debian, following the instructions on [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce) page.

(mostly `apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies`, but do read all the page).

Here you can find which packages are installed on Ubuntu when installing [xubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/xubuntu-desktop).

If you want to learn to recreate xubuntu-desktop, read the Xfce wiki page and try to match the applications found on xubuntu-desktop to their Debian variants (quit possibly named the same of very similarly).

Comment: thanks for the edits, will try to markdown more usefully next time :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already installed xfce4. This package is okay but I'm specifically missing the nice gui and the default theme which I get with `xubuntu-desktop`. Please let me know if you know about the installation/config of the default appearance and how I can get on `xfce4`.

Comment: well, if you really want, you can follow [this howto](http://linuxthemer.blogspot.nl/2014/06/xubuntu-with-pure-debian-base-from.html), especially step 2 seems to be what you need.